Homotopy equivalence of realization of nerve of a cover.
I was reading the paper "Homology fibration and group completion theorem" by Segal and McDuff. During the proof of Proposition 6 (of local-to-global flavor) he states the existence of spaces $E_\mathfrak{B}$, $|\mathfrak{B}|$ homotopy equivalent to the starting spaces $E, B$.
From what I seem to be understanding, and here comes the actual question, it seems to me that the following fact is true (and unproven in the paper and its references with this generality):
Let $B$ be a paracompact, locally contractible and contractible space and let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a basis of contractible open sets. $\mathfrak{B}$ can be seen as a category with the basis open sets as objects  and their inclusions as morphisms. Then its geometric realization (or precisely, the realization of its nerve) is homotopic to $B$, and hence contractible.
I have come across other lemmas similar to this where you can take any cover of contractible sets but they all use some kind of hypothesis on the finite intersections of the open sets: all of them have to be contractible. However I can't manage to prove "their" version.
In particular I can't understand how the fact that $\mathfrak{B}$ is a basis should be fundamental (I seem to have found that the equivalence is false if I replace $\mathfrak{B}$ with a generic open cover without hypothesis on the intersections: just think about covering $S^1$ with two enlarged semicircles).
Maybe some of you can quote a reference for this, or even better know a way to avoid it.
Thanks

does 4G.2 answer your question? It's not stated in terms of geometric realizations but it's pretty similar. You need partitions of unity.

@AndresMejia it does not quite answer the question (however it is another way of proving the other homotopy equivalence he states, namely that of $E_\mathfrak{B}\rightarrow E$). I think ultimately that the space he is looking at is not the realization of a basis but the realization of the disintegration of $B$ with respect to the basis (that may suggests that the lemma of my question be false)
